# I want to toggle a pushbutton and display it on tkinter GUI

Tags: rpi.gpio, tkinter

I want to toggle a pushbutton and show its changes on a label using tkinter.

If I press the button it shows "on" on the label and when I press again it shows "off" on the label

So I try these codes and If I'm trying the wrong code please help me write the correct using tkinter.

I have a problem in combining this code

```py
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

GPIO.setup(22,GPIO.IN,up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

while(1):

    if GPIO.input(22)==1:

        if bs == False :

            x.set("on")

            bs=True

            sleep(0.5)

        else:

            x.set("off")

            bs=False

            sleep(0.5)
```

This works okay but I want to connect it to a GUI label to print on it on or off.

Here is the tkinter code

```py
import tkinter.*

root = tk()
x = StringVar()

s=Label(root,textvariable=x)

s.grid(column=0,row=0)

root.mainloop()
```

When I try to combine it I make it like this

```py
from Tkinter import *

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

GPIO.setup(7,GPIO.IN)

b=False
def check_button1():

    if GPIO.input(7)== 1:

        if b == False :

            labelText1.set("on")

            print"on"

            b=True

            time.sleep(0.5)
        else:
            labelText1.set("off")

            print"off"

            b=False

            time.sleep(0.5)
    mamdouh.after(10,check_button1)
mamdouh = Tk()

labelText1 = StringVar()


x1 = Label(mamdouh,textvariable=labelText1) 

x1.config(font=('Helvetica',25,'bold'))

x1.grid(row=0,column=0)

mamdouh.title("mamdouh") 

mamdouh.geometry('1200x700')

mamdouh.after(10,check_button1)

mamdouh.mainloop()
```

but it didn't works it keeps blank every time I press the push button actually If it works well I will put 17 push button 
So how I can make this toggle push button on an Label?

Comment: I'm not a python or RPi.GPIO user but you want to make use of a *callback* with the pin functioning as an interrupt (RPi.GPIO should have that feature but I don't know the details).

Answer (score 2):

You could use a separate loop that checks the GPIO state. Since it would block the main program from running root.mainloop() you have to create a thread that runs parallel to it and controls the label.

```
from Tkinter import *
from threading import Thread
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(7,GPIO.IN)

class check_button(Thread):

    def __init__(self, labelText):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.labelText = labelText
        self.b = False

    def checkloop(self):
        while True:
            if GPIO.input(7) == 1:
                if self.b == False :
                    self.labelText.set("on")
                    print "on"
                    self.b = True
                else:
                    self.labelText.set("off")
                    print "off"
                    self.b = False
                while GPIO.input(7) == 1: pass

mamdouh = Tk()
labelText1 = StringVar()
x1 = Label(mamdouh,textvariable=labelText1) 
x1.config(font=('Helvetica',25,'bold'))
x1.grid(row=0,column=0)
mamdouh.title("mamdouh") 
mamdouh.geometry('1200x700')

chk1 = check_button(labelText1)
c1 = Thread(target=chk1.checkloop)
c1.start()

mamdouh.mainloop()
```

Comment: not working I will edit the question to add the code

Comment: please check it again

Comment: @mamdouhabdelfatah I updated the code, try again.

Comment: it works thanks alot , what if I want to make this for two or more push button with two or more labels ? what I will make ?

Comment: @mamdouhabdelfatah Good to hear, would be really nice if you could accept my answer as correct =) To expand the functionality to other GPIO pins you would simply have to include the GPIO pin's index into the check_button class by adding it to its init method's arguments, then save it as self.gpio, and of course include self.gpio in the if-statement.

You can then spawn another instance of the check_button thread in the main program and start it the same way you did before with chk1/c1. Welcome to object oriented programming ;)

Comment: I try making two push buttons but it was so slow some times it make what I want and some times no how can I solve it

Comment: Well, without some code it will be very hard to figure out. The instructions I gave to you should work.

Comment: Actually, I want to make 17 push button  so I will make 17 object from that class  so I tried making one like you first it works perfect so I tried to add one more push button and make an object for it and the problem was that it is soooo slow some times not responding and some times respond slow

Comment: here is the code   :       http://pastebin.com/Zqxu0XnG

Comment: The sleep time of 0.5 seconds stops the threads from responding so you could try to reduce it, or instead poll the pin with `while GPIO.input(7) == 1: pass` so it unblocks as soon as the button is released.

Comment: can you add it to your code please ^_^, because I don't know how I will put it

Comment: @mamdouhabdelfatah Well, done so. I just replaced time.sleep with the mentioned while loop. This way, the function is not blocking for a fixed guessed duration (what you did) to avoid repeated triggering, but instead waits for the user to release the button (what you actually meant to do).

Comment: it is very very very slow again

Comment: Have you removed the lines with sleep?

Comment: Yes I make what you said to me but it still slow and some times when I press it don't show any response